# How do I get a number (or text) from a data frame in a code chunk in to text in RMarkdown html output?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I can get this to work when the output is a word document, but not when the output is html.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_notebook: default
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
mtcars

```

Number `r  mtcars %>% select(mpg) %>% slice(1)`
````

In word the output is

> Number 21

But when the output is html, I get a whole table.

[image]

Is there a way to just get the text in the html output?

It would be used in text, so I don't want the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slice` returns the class dataframe hence you get output as table

```
mtcars %>% select(mpg) %>% slice(1) %>% class
#[1] "data.frame"
```

You need output as vector instead, so any way that would give final output as vector would work. Here, I use `pull` (keeping in mind you are using `tidyverse`) to get output as vector (here `numeric`).

```
mtcars %>% select(mpg) %>% slice(1) %>% pull %>% class
#[1] "numeric"
```

So do,

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_notebook: default
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
mtcars
```

Number `r  mtcars %>% select(mpg) %>% slice(1) %>% pull`
````

[image]

This doesn't change the output in Word and it would still work as before.